# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2.283.00 - 5.331.00'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a program 'Build A Python App That Tracks Amazon Prices!' but when I run the program it gives
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2.283.00 - 5.331.00'. I tried looking up for solutions but nothing worked. Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib

URL = "https://www.amazon.in/Nike-Trainer-Training-Shoes-8-924206-060/dp/B07FKG4SGQ/ref=sr_1_2? 
dchild=1&keywords=nike+shoes+for+men&qid=1609408052&sr=8-2"

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}


def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price.replace('₹\xa0' , '').replace(',', '.'))

    print(title)
    print(converted_price)

    if (converted_price > 4000):
        send_mail()


def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)    
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('aryan111san@gmail.com', 'ezrdsmxfokoeihlb')

    subject = 'Price fell down!'
    body = 'check flipkart link https://www.amazon.in/Nike-Trainer-Training-Shoes-8-924206- 
    060/dp/B07FKG4SGQ/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=nike+shoes+for+men&qid=1609408052&sr=8-2'    

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
      'aryan111san@gmail.com',
      'aryaditya007@gmail.com',
      msg
   )

    print("Email has been sent!")

    server.quit()

check_price()
```

Comment: '2.283.00 - 5.331.00' is clearly not a single price, and therefore cannot be converted to float. That format seems like a range for the price, e.g., price_from and price_to. You should first split and the convert each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is that '2.283.00 - 5.331.00' is not something that can be converted to a float.  It expects a format like '1.23'.

First of all it's a range, so you need to split that into two numbers on ' - '.

```
prices = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text().split(' - ')
```

Then replace the thousand separator ',' with '' on each price with:

```
price.replace('₹\xa0' , '').replace(',', '')
```

The better option might be to import locale and convert each of the prices (without the currency symbol) with locale.atof().

Comment: Thanks that helped. I changed the product and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell `2.283.00` is not a number, you got it from `2,283.00` which python cant easiy parse, but did you know that you can have thousand delimited in python using underscores? so `2_283.00` is a number in python.
also you are attempting to parse a range of numbers, you should split them first

just change

```
converted_price = float(price.replace('₹\xa0' , '').replace(',', '.'))
```

to

```
converted_price = [float(item) for item in (price.replace('₹\xa0' , '').replace(',', '_').split()[slice(0,3,2)])]
```

`converted_price` is now a list of 2 items, pick the one you want or perform any math you want on them (like getting the average for instance)

Answer (score 0):

'2.283.00 - 5.331.00' is clearly not a single price, and therefore cannot be converted to float. That format seems like a range for the price, e.g., price_from and price_to. You should first split and convert each of them. An easy way to do it is via regular expressions. Then, modify the `check_price()` as follows:

```py
import re

def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    
    # Replace comma with empty string to allow float conversion: float('2283.00') is fine, float('2,283.00') is not
    price = price.replace(',', '')
    
    # Use regular expression to identify prices. 
    # If a single price (eg € 2283.00), then prices = [('2283.00', '.00')] 
    # If range (eg € 2283.00 - € 5331.00), then prices = [('2283.00', '.00'), ('5331.00', '.00')] 
    prices = re.findall(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?)', price)

    # Iterate over the prices to do some action
    for price, decimals in prices:      
        print(float(price))
        if (float(price) > 4000):
            send_mail()
```